# Plot shows wrong points in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm doing a Python test to draw some functions.

The problem is that the points that both functions intersect at the same X are not correct.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = np.arange(-10,10,1)

def f(x): 
    return x+30

def z(x):
    return x*x

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.plot(x, f(x).astype(np.int))
plt.plot(x, z(x).astype(np.int))
plt.title("Gráfico de función" )
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(f(x) - z(x)))).flatten()
plt.plot(x[idx], f(x[idx]), 'ro')

plt.legend(["F","Z"])

plt.show()
```

I expect only two points, but in the plot appeared four. Two of them are incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is not with the plot itself but with your methods of getting the points for this case when the intersection is an integer value. When taking np.diff of np.sign you go from -1 to 0 to 1 at the intersection points giving you 1 at 4 locations. If the intersection was not an int, you would get -1 to 1 and get the correct answer. If you try this instead you can find the integer intersection points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = np.arange(-10,10,1)

def f(x): 
    return x+30.

def z(x):
    return x*x

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.plot(x, f(x).astype(np.int))
plt.plot(x, z(x).astype(np.int))
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

#Say only get args where there is no sign (i.e. zero).
idx = np.argwhere((np.sign(f(x) - z(x))==0)) 

plt.plot(x[idx], f(x[idx]), 'ro')

plt.legend(["F","Z"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
The above code only works if you have perfect integer intersections. To arbitrarily do both you need to check to see if a perfect integer intersection exists before deciding which method to use. I just used a simple `for` loop to do this but I am sure there are more elegant ways to do this.

```
for v in np.sign(f(x) - z(x)):
    if v==0:
        idx = np.argwhere(np.sign(f(x) - z(x))==0)
        break
    else:
        idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(f(x) - z(x))))
```

Comment: Works in several cases. For example for 

def f(x): 
    return -4*x+1000

def z(x):
    return 2*x*x

In that case, the plot doesn't show the points. Why can be? Thanks

Comment: That is because now you do not have perfect integer values for the intersection point

Comment: I mad an edit to the answer. The errors are due to perfect integer intersection points which give you additional intersections since there is a zero.

Comment: Hi. I tried the code you wrote and didn't work. Here's an screen capture of this. [link] (https://imgur.com/U25sb7d)

Comment: So the code works and is doing exactly what it is supposed to. The issue now is that you have plots with very large slopes and your x resolution is too low to handle it accurately. If you use .01 instead of 1 in `x=np.arange(-10,10,.01)` you will see that the correct answer results.

Comment: In addition, you may want to use floats instead of integers because otherwise the plots will be blocky.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you BenT!